# Model.to_a throws undefined method to_a

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I wanted to resolve this Rails 4 deprecation warning:

Relation#all is deprecated. If you want to eager-load a relation, you can call #load (e.g. Post.where(published: true).load). If you want to get an array of records from a relation, you can call #to_a (e.g. Post.where(published: true).to_a).

So when I turn Model.all to Model.to_a it throws undefined method to_a.

When I try Model.scoped.to_a it works like for example for where and scope chains.

Should I go through scoped or is there a better solution?

Comment: Please show relevant fragment where you use `all` method.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you really want an array, you should use:

```
Model.all.to_a
```

Since Rails 4 `all` method returns relation, `Relation#all` is deprecated.

Comment: So the method Relation#all will not be dropped and just returns a relation since Rails 4?

Comment: It probably will be dropped. But `Model.all` method returns relation since Rails 4.